# Sidecar, Touch Bar and active Apps

Tags: ipad, macos-catalina, sidecar

I have a problem with the Sidecar and Touch Bar feature of iPad and MacOS Catalina.

I can connect and see everything on the iPad including the Touchbar.
If I focus an application which is displayed on the iPad the Touchbar shows the corresponding Touchbar correctly.

After focussing an application on one of my other displays (MacBook or external HDMI displays) the Touch Bar does not update and change.
If I put that application on the iPad screen, then the TouchBar changes and shows the corresponding items.

This is really annoying when I am working with programming IDEs with nice TouchBar support. But I really don't want to put that IDE on my smaller iPad screen.

Is anyone else experiencing this and/or has a workaround?
Cheers